# Why is StatusCode not set from Mvc when exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a simple application:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        finally
        {
            var test = context.Response.StatusCode;
            //test=200 when exception is thrown from Mvc()
        }
    });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Why is the `Response.StatusCode` not set if a controller throws an `Exception`? This seems quite surprising and undocumented. It seems to work inconsistent with the concept of the pipeline where eg. **401** and **404** have been set at this point. Is this a bug or is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error handling is not the responsibility/concern of the MVC middleware. The exception will just bubble up and other middleware (such as developer exception page or exception handler) should handle this error.

You can try this by adding `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` or `UseExceptionHandler()` *before* the `UseMvc()` call. For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/path/to/error/page");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Good point. I tried the ExceptionHandler middleware and it works ok except it says in documentation it will re-execute my request which seems like crazy behaviour. Why would anyone want that?

Comment: It re-executes the request using the path/handler you've provided. E.g. it will set the request path to `/path/to/error/page` and re-execute it. It won't re-execute the _same_ request.

Comment: If I add app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/error"); which returns 200 and api/throws throws an exception, it will actually hit the breakpoint in api/throws twice.

Comment: Ok it will actually reissue the same request when used with app.UseExceptionHandler() which is crazy but it seems to have been removed from the next version. app.UseExceptionHandler("/path/to/error") works but the documentation could have been better.

Answer (score 2):

The 500 status code is set by the ASP.NET middleware before the exception is returned to the caller. If you test your API with Postman you will see it reports a Status Code 500.

The reason you do not see it in your example is because your async function is further up the pipeline than the code that detects the exception and returns the 500 status code.

As an experiment add the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` code to `Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        finally
        {
            var test = context.Response.StatusCode;
        }
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

When you run with this code the StatusCode is 500. However, if you move the code to AFTER the `app.Use(...`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        finally
        {
            var test = context.Response.StatusCode;
        }
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In this code you will find that the StatusCode is 500. So it's all about the middleware setting the correct status code. It depends where your code is in the pipeline as to what status code it sees.